# Writing to textbox in another process in Win32 (c++)

Tags: c++, c, windows

Suppose you need to write a process or service (process1) that will read or write to textbox in another application or process (process 2). How is it done? 
Is the name of the textbox of process 2 is written in some sort of a registry so i can get it from some sort of a system call?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your two programs willing to communicate with each other in order to achieve this?

Comment: Suppose you have just an exe file. That when you run it you have a window with a textbox in it. You don't know anything about the name of the textbox. You need to create another program that will identify that that specific exe runs and in that case write "foo" (for example) to the textbox in that exe file. i have only the exe file of the first program. So i cannot communicate with it directly.

Comment: I say normally they would not communicate using a textbox as the mechanism. Instead the programs would use sockets, shared memory or some other communication method.

Comment: Textbox is not a means of communication over here. It is just I think that when you run an exe in windows MFC objects are registered somewhere and it you can write to them somehow. Because that exe is "closed" i don't know how you can directly change the content of that textbox

Comment: MFC is a 3rd party library, as far as Windows is concerned. In general, a windows application doesn't use MFC. You also seem to use the terms *application* and *process* interchangeably. A process is the kernel object that hosts an application. I'm also not sure I understand what you want to achieve. If you wish to modify a particular control, you will have to be able to identify that control. If you *"don't know anything about"* the control, you will not be able to identify it. Changing random controls' contents is fairly simple, though.

Comment: As i understand you need to do some sort of hooking and injecting the dll that can observe some action in that program exe.

Comment: No hooking, DLL injection, or other crime is going to help, if you cannot identify the target (victim).

Comment: But i know the name of the other program exe. Or it is still not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The text box is identified by an ID number that you can find using Spy++.  Use FindWindow and EnumChildWindows to find the HWND of the target text box. With the HWND you can SendMessage WM_GETTEXT or WM_SETTEXT. Note: This won't work if the security level of the two processes differ.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can i somehow download source code of spy++ and integrate into my service application. I just wanted to make it completely automatic without viewing and manually inserting the IDs.

Comment: Sounds like an ad hoc hack... are you supposed to launch this Spy++ manually each time before using your program, or does it come with some API?

Comment: @Lundin: spy++ is a program, not an API. the control id's are usually not dynamic.

Comment: I didn't want to launch the Spy++ manually. I wanted that my program can be able to identify the .exe application running and alter its textbox.

Comment: @ZAxy: Starting with Windows Vista, *Session 0* is isolated from interactive user sessions (see [Impact of Session 0 Isolation on Services and Drivers in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293.aspx)). You cannot easily access GUI objects in an interactive user session from Session 0.

Comment: It would be unusual and improbable for the control IDs to change. You should have a pretty good solution by assuming it is constant.