# Service reading controls from from another third party executable in windows

Tags: c++, c

I wanted to ask you about service process that needs to read controls from a third party executable that has suppose some buttons and textboxes in windows in c++. I know that with windows vista and on there is  session 0 isolation. But still is there any way i can do that without the source code of that third party?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

P.S if i don't have the third party code , i can't use IPC.

Comment: I don't know of any way.  It would be a massive security flaw if it was easily possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to textbox in another process in Win32 (c++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279348/writing-to-textbox-in-another-process-in-win32-c)

Comment: Hang on - you already asked this question yesterday... closing as dup.

Comment: This time i asked from a service and not a simple desktop app